# Passed URL string not interpret as a string

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I read quite some articles and tried some approaches, but couldn't get it to work.

```
htmlCode += '<button id="' + addButtonId + '" title="' + addButtonTitle + '" class="button" onclick="getProductUrl(' + url + '); return false;"><span><span>' + addWithButonTitle + '</span></span></button>';
```

and the function itself:

```
getProductUrl: function(url) {
        return setLocation('\'' + decodeURIComponent(url) + document.getElementById('qty_field').value + '\'');
    },
```

Apparently, the string value of the `url` is not treated as a string. I get an error of missing bracket here: `getProductUrl(http:`^`//...rest of the url`. Of course the problem is not in the bracket, but in the fact that the `//` are treated as a start of a comment.

So the thing that I have to do is to pass this `url` string value CORRECTLY as a string.
I tried first decoding and then passing (because `decodeURIComponent(url)` should return string. Also I tried `String(url)` and `url + ""`. Also somehow escaping the special characters: `url.replace('/','\/')` or even the `/g` thingy, which didn't work at all.

So, all these approaches were unsuccessful. I would really appreciate a hint or a solution here.

Comment: What's the code surrounding  `onclick="getProductUrl(' + url + ');"`? I doubt that's the complete line.

Comment: @FelixKling - I updated my question by putting the full line of code. :)

Comment: In that case your code should look like:
`htmlCode += '<button id="' + addButtonId + '" title="' + addButtonTitle + '" class="button" onclick="getProductUrl(\'' + url + '\'); return false;"><span><span>' + addWithButonTitle + '</span></span></button>';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one

```
onclick="getProductUrl('" + url + "');"
```

For your updated line of code:

```
htmlCode += '<button id="' + addButtonId + '" title="' + addButtonTitle + '" class="button" onclick="getProductUrl(\'' + url + '\'); return false;"><span><span>' + addWithButonTitle + '</span></span></button>';
```

Comment: I updated my post by putting the whole line of code where the `onclick` is. Please take a look. And I also tried your approach, which didn't work, because `url` is being treated as a directly typed string, instead of a variable. Maybe after checking out my update you will give another way out. :)

Comment: Check the comment I made bellow your question. It's all about escaping.